# My datetimepicker does not appear in symfony 3.4

Tags: javascript, symfony, bootstrap-datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

here I am trying to customize two of my fields of my form of adding schedules, using for these two fields a datetimepicker, that of http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/
[datetimepicker link](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) and for that I downloaded the corresponding zip file on github, and place the different files (css, js) in the respective folders.

But in the display, I only have fields and the calendar and time do not appear.

Here is the rendering of my form in image [image of my form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BeN4.jpg).

Here is the import file of my css and js: base.html.twig

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<meta name="description" content="Avec Doctix Prenez facilement un Rendez-vous">
<meta name="author" content="Med">
<title>{% block title %}Doctix{% endblock %}</title>
    {% block stylesheets %}
     <!-- BASE CSS -->
<link href="{{ asset('public/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{ asset('public/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{ asset('public/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{ asset('public/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker-standalone.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{ asset('public/css/style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{ asset('public/css/menu.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{ asset('public/css/vendors.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{ asset('public/css/icon_fonts/css/all_icons_min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{ asset('public/css/fullcalendar.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{ asset('bundles/fullcalendar/css/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- YOUR CUSTOM CSS -->
<link href="{{ asset('public/css/custom.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{ asset('public/css/common.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
 <!-- SPECIFIC CSS -->
<link href="{{ asset('public/css/date_picker.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">  

    {% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}

    <!-- Modernizr -->
    <script src="{{ asset('public/js/modernizr.js') }}"></script>

    <!-- COMMON SCRIPTS -->
    <script src="{{ asset('public/js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('public/js/common_scripts.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('public/js/functions.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('public/assets/validate.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('public/js/fullcalendar/lib/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('public/js/fullcalendar/lib/moment.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('public/js/moment.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('public/js/locale-all.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('public/js/lang-all.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('public/js/fullcalendar/lib/jquery-ui.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('public/js/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('public/js/fullcalendar/lang/fr.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('public/js/fullcalendar/lang-all.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('public/js/fullcalendar.default-settings.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('bundles/fosjsrouting/js/router.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ path('fos_js_routing_js', {"callback": "fos.Router.setData"}) }}"></script>
  <!-- SPECIFIC SCRIPTS -->
  <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
  <script src="{{ asset('public/js/map_listing.js') }}"></script>
  <script src="{{ asset('public/js/infobox.js') }}"></script>
  <script src="{{ asset('public/js/jquery.selectbox-0.2.js') }}"></script>
  <script>

 <script src="{{ asset('public/js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
 <script src="{{ asset('public/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js') }}"></script>
 <script src="{{asset('public/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js') }}"></script>
 <script src="{{asset('public/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js') }}"> 
 </script>
           {% endblock %}
```

And here is my ScheduleType form: ScheduleType.php

```
     <?php

  namespace Doctix\MedecinBundle\Form;

  use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
  use Doctix\AdminBundle\Form\SpecialiteType;
  use Doctix\UserBundle\Form\UserType;
  use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
  use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
  use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateTimeType;
  use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
  use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
    class ScheduleType extends AbstractType
   {
 /**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
  {
     $builder->remove('user')
            ->remove('specialite')
            ->add('title')
            ->add('date_debut', DateTimeType::class, array(
                'widget' => 'single_text',
                'html5' => true,
                'required' => true,
                'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control input-inline datetimepicker',
                                 'data-provide' => 'datetimepicker',
                                 'data-format' => 'dd-mm-yyyy HH:ii',  
                                    ),


            ))
            ->add('date_fin', DateTimeType::class,array(
                'widget' => 'single_text',
                'html5' => true,
                'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control input-inline datetimepicker',
                                 'data-provide' => 'datetimepicker',
                                 'data-format' => 'dd-mm-yyyy HH:ii',  
                                    ),


            ))
            ->add('submit', SubmitType::class);

}
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Doctix\MedecinBundle\Entity\Schedule'
    ));
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getBlockPrefix()
{
    return 'doctix_medecinbundle_schedule';
}


  }
```

And finally my view new.html.twig

```
   <div class="content-wrapper">
   <div class="container-fluid">

                            <!-- Breadcrumbs-->   
        <ul class="breadcrumb">
     <li> 
       <h1>Ajout de nouveaux plannings</h1>
     </li>
              </ul>

  <div style="width: 900px; float: left;">   

                    <div class="row">       

                                {{ form_start(form) }}


                          <div class="form-group">    

                          {{ form_label(form.title) }}           

                            {{ form_widget(form.title) }}

                          </div>                
  </div>                                
                           <div class="row">

                          <div class="form-group">    

                          {{ form_label(form.date_debut) }}           
                          <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker'>
                            {{ form_widget(form.date_debut, { 'attr': { 'class': 'form-control input-inline datetimepicker' }}) }}
                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                            </span>
                          </div>                
                          </div>  
                            </div>
                                      <div class="row">
                          <div class="form-group">    

                          {{ form_label(form.date_fin) }}           
                          <div  class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker'> 
                             {{ form_widget(form.date_fin, { 'attr': { 'class': 'form-control input-inline datetimepicker' }}) }}

                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                            </span>
                          </div>                
                          </div>          
                                    </div>           


                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{ form_row(form.submit, { 'label': 'Ajouter' }) }}
                    </div>


                    {{ form_end(form) }}

                    </div>



   <ul>
      <li>
         <a id="eventLink" href="{{ path('schedule_index') }}">Retour à la liste</a>
     </li>
  </ul>


         </div>
    </div>
   </div>           

   <div id="calendar-holder">

    {% include '@FullCalendar/Calendar/calendar.html.twig' %}


   </div>


    {% block javascript %}


            <script type="text/javascript">


                     $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker();

            </script>
              {% endblock %}
```

That's it just shows me my two fields but not the desired datetimepicker

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 different `<div>` elements with the same id:

```
<div  class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker'>
```

In the DOM you cannot re-use an id. You need to either give each element its own id and then tag it with the datetimepicker() function, or use a different approach and use a class and tag it that way.

Option 1:

```
<div  class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
...
<div  class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker2'>
...

{% block javascript %}
    <script type="text/javascript">
         $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
         $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker();
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Option 2:

```
<div  class='input-group date datetimepicker'>
...
<div  class='input-group date datetimepicker'>
...

{% block javascript %}
    <script type="text/javascript">
         $('div.datetimepicker').datetimepicker();
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Both should be equivalent, but Option 2 is easier to expand to other fields (and easier to maintain in the long run.

Comment: Hi @ehymel, 
even with your suggestions this does not change anything, no display of the datetimepicker

Answer (score 0):

Personnaly I had to use the attribute

```
'data-toggle' => 'datetimepicker'
```

instead of

```
'data-provide' => 'datetimepicker'
```

It should look like that (may be a little different with the class name as I'm using BS4 datetimepicker "tempusdominus"):

```
    ->add('dateNaissance', DateType::class, array(
        'html5' => false,
        'widget' => 'single_text',
        'attr' => array(
            'class' => 'form-control datetimepicker-input',
            'data-toggle' => 'datetimepicker'
        )
    ))
```

Then in javascript I do the following thing:

```
$('your selector...').datetimepicker({
                date: dateVal,
                locale : 'fr',
                viewMode: 'years',
                buttons: {
                    showClose : true
                },
                format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
                collapse: true
            });
```

And dont forget to check if you've got no js error in your browser.

Hope it will help.

Regards,

Maxime

Comment: Hi @MaximeADT, i tried your suggestion, but i have no change. My console show me that error: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined in '  $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({ '

Comment: It seems that you're missing JQuery ;) Import it in your project and this error might disapear

Comment: Not in the page you're trying to use datetimepicker. Trust me.
Or just to verify, in your page, enter the following command in your console:
$('body')
If there's no error then the problem might be in the order you're declaring your scripts importation

Comment: There's no error in my console when i enter $('body').

Comment: I think it's a mismatch of jquery and bootstrap version.
I use bootstrap4 and jquery3.3.1.
But if I import the cdn versions of bootstrap3.2.0 and jquery2.1.0, it seems to work but still the display is so far not perfect

Comment: Ok...For BS4 is recommend TempusDominus instead of enosdan (or something like that)
And be sure that you've got the right version of your components together. USe npm if you want it to get all dependencies with right version ;)

Comment: Ok, @MaximeADT,
I followed your recommendation, and I used the tempusdominus, and it works almost, except that when I click on the calendar icon it fills me the field with the date and time of the day and does not show me not the calendar

Comment: Well thats better than before apprently. Now, I can only recommand you to read the documentation:
https://tempusdominus.github.io/bootstrap-4/Usage/
And if you want to pass the form a registered value of date, then catch the value in JS and pass it in this line:
    date: dateVal,
This will be the default value of the field but the doc explains it well :)

Comment: I read the doc, but I just want when I click on the calendar icon, that my calendar and the time is displayed. Instead, when I click this fills me the input with the date and time of the day.Thanks

Comment: Your calendar isnt display you mean?

Comment: Yes that's it. Just the timepicker is displayed and not the datepicker

Comment: Dont you get any error in your console? And be sure to run this after 'document' got loaded

Comment: By 'this' I mean the javascript part of the answer i provided you